# install rpcgen on debian lenny

Tags: linux, makefile, debian

I am trying to compile VXI11 source codes on my debian - lenny, but I get this error:

```
make
rpcgen -M vxi11.x
make: rpcgen: command not found
```

Anyone know to rpcgen get intalled?
Cant find solution. Any help is most appreciated.

Thanks
Petr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian and Ubuntu, the `apt-file` command will tell you what package you can install to get a particular file. First install the `apt-file` package and run `apt-file update`. Then `apt-file search rpcgen` will show all the packages that include a file whose name contains `rpcgen`. Since you know you're looking for an executable, you can restrict the search to `apt-file search bin/rpcgen`.

If you're going to compile a C or C++ program on Debian or Ubuntu, start by installing the `build-essential` package.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-bin
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I've already tried this, but I always end up with error:


E: Couldn't find package libc6-dev-bin

Do I need any other packages? gcc???

Thanks